# How to find a regex for url value

Tags: regex

product-resource/monitor-arms/**cutsheets**/edge

I am trying to get "cutsheets" from the string above.  I was trying to select the last "/" and get everything up to the previous "/".

Do you have any idea how to do this?

Thanks for the help-

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/161738/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-url

Comment: Is it specifically 'cutsheets' you're trying to match, or do you have more URLs with different words that have to be removed/replaced?

Comment: I have urls with different words.  I was trying to select everything before the last "/" until another "/".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this regex to capture the string `cutsheets`,

```
.*\/(.*)\/
```

OR

```
.*\/(.*)\/.*$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/lT7fG6)

Answer (score 0):

Your reasoning seems good. This should match what you need: `\/([^\/]+?)\/[^\/]+?$`.

Example [here](http://regex101.com/r/tM8lA7).

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `.*/.*/(.*)/.*`

(P.S. the code pasted by npinti got my the 2nd word, i.e. 'monitor-arms'. I used [Expresso](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&sqi=2&ved=0CB8QFjAA&url=http://www.ultrapico.com/expresso.htm&ei=5ZaiU4HAJunE4gSWpIDACg&usg=AFQjCNHBDYozPkl_oJ9VVgbKmZL1jgNIRQ&sig2=eI71ETrW3QhWg-0vR0HUIw&bvm=bv.69411363,d.ZGU) to check)